# Checking for bit flags

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, flags

I'm trying to check for a bit in a flags value of which flags can be |'d together. So far i'm using this

```
 if ((someclass.flags | CONST_SOMEFLAG) == someclass.flags)
```

to check if its true or false but is there a more "elegant" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will work fine, but it's more conventional to use &:

```
if (flags & MASK) . . .
```

This is likely because on some processors testing a register for != 0 is faster than testing for equality with a stored value.

Comment: This may not work if `sizeof(flags) > sizeof(long)`, for example a 64-bit word with a 32-bit compilation.  The reason being the result of the bitwise math will be evaluated as an `int` which will truncate high order bits and thus evaluate as `false`.

Comment: See the c99 spec, 6.3.1.8p2. If the two operands of a binary operator are two different integer sizes, the smaller is promoted in a value-preserving way to the size of the larger.

Comment: unfortunately there are plenty of c89 compilers that do not comply.

Comment: Perhaps. In those cases, it's probably wise to make sure your flags variable is an int. In almost 30 years of C programming, I've never run into this problem in practice, even back in the old K&R days. I *have* been bitten by signed shift-rights and signed/unsigned comparisons.

Comment: I've been hit with basic finite field math, for reference:  https://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/include/impl/sn.h

Answer (score 2):

Use bitwise OR to set the flags, use bitwise AND to test, like this:

`if (someclass.flags & CONST_SOMEFLAG) ...`

Comment: Note, if given more than one bit for `SOMEFLAG`, this will return `true` if any of the bits are set, whereas OP code would checks if all are set.

Comment: The standard idiom for checking that all of a set of flags are set is `(flags & mask) == mask`, but `(flags | mask) == flags` is an interesting choice on some ISAs for compile-time-constant masks, especially AArch64 where bitwise instructions can use a different immediate encoding than compare.  (Unless they use EOR as a compare...) But worse on other ISAs. https://godbolt.org/z/8P79sz4h3 - actually clang has other tricks up its sleeve: it makes asm like `if (((~flags) & MASK) == 0)` when that's better. So as usual, write something readable. (Unless micro-optimizing for GCC or other non-clang)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to know is, if the flag bit is set among all the other possibly set or unset bits. The canonical way to do this, is to bitwise and (&) test for being nonzero

```
if( someclass.flags & CONST_SOMEFLAG )
```

Comment: OP is correct. It checks whether setting the flag would leave the (total) value unchanged.

Comment: His original code will work fine, it's just unconventional. If ORing a mask with a value doesn't change the value, then the mask bits are set (and the other bits are not bothered or tested).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, you're right. I removed the wrong statement.